# find all jscontroller divs in google playstore with soup Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get all reviews from an app of google playstore.
I must not use Selenium so I was thinking about BeatifulSoup.
My problem is when I try to find `<div jscontroller="H6eOGe" jsmodel="y8Aajc" jsdata="yf3HXc;_;$0 YjFXEf;_;$1">` the response is `[]`

With Selenium I do that with: `driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@jscontroller="H6eOGe"]')`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.session()
app = 'com.mercadopago.wallet'
response = session.get('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id={}&hl=es_AR&showAllReviews=true'.format(app)).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
app_name = soup.find("h1", {"class": "AHFaub"}).text
reviews = soup.find_all("div", {"jscontroller": "H6eOGe"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. The problem is with the HTML you are getting.
If you do:

```
with open('source.html','w') as f:
   f.write(response)
```

And then you open that file with a text editor, you will notice that it doesnt contain any div with jscontroller="H6eOGe" attribute.
My guess is that these divs are somehow created by some script when the browser renders the page.

Anyway, the information you are looking for is in the HTML, but you have to parse it differently